# Is there a way to move objects without using glTranslatef in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, animation, glut

I'm new to OpenGL and I was wondering if there is a method that could help me simulate certain animations -such as jumping or flying- without using the glTranslatef. Any ideas about the matter ?

Comment: I'm just curious: any particular reason to why you want to avoid explicit vertex translation?

Comment: "without using the glTranslatef function via GLUT" GLUT does not provide `glTranslatef`. You can tell what are GLUT functions and what aren't by the prefix. `gl` means OpenGL. `glut` means GLUT.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw I'm trying to make an object move and then come back to its original place, thought maybe I could utilize the vertex arrays in order to do so.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right, sorry about the typo.

Comment: @mojave_ranger: You can _arbitrarily_ position the object with transforms. If you want it to "come back to its original place", just provide a transform of (0, 0, 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate your geometry before submitting it to OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a vector / matrix library such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) to manage your geometry.  Both have a collection of affine transformation routines which will allow you to do what you're looking for.  Once the transformations are applied to your geometry, they can then be rendered very easily with routines supplied in the libraries.  I prefer Eigen, since the documentation is a bit more complete, but they both work well.